# Sql left join on Id and date

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a table A that contain a record Id and a date column.

I need left join this with another table B by the same record Id and by the date so that I only show the records from the first table B for the given record Id for that date.

Table A:

```
2017-11-03 | 123456 | 5 | 6
```

Table B:

```
2017-11-03 | 123456
2017-11-05 | 123456
```

When join together by Id and date I want to see:

```
2017-11-03 | 123456 | 5 | 6
2017-11-05 | 123456
```

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You pretty much said the answer in your question... What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A left join, by definition, only shows rows from the left table-in this case, B. Any rows in B that are not matched, show nulls in the table A columns. So, ths code should produce the output you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM B
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Date = B.Date
```

Comment: Please explain why this answers the question! Regard that code-only answers are not quite helpful...